# Plotting a 3d surface in tikz, with a limit to the infinity

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot the function `1/(x²+y²)`, but since it tends to infinity in `(0,0)`, I get a horrible plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=both]
    \addplot3 [surf] {1 / (x^2 + y^2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By restricting the domain of z, I get anyway a not so nice plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=both,restrict z to domain=0:1]
    \addplot3 [surf] {1 / (x^2 + y^2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to get something smooth, which finish in a circle (the circle of the intersection of this function with the plane z=1 for example).

Something like this would be great:

[image]

Comment: For that I think you need a different parametrization of the surface. Otherwise you will get that sampling behavior.

Comment: But there may be a way to intersect this surface with the plane z=1, and "hide" what is above it, or something like that...

Comment: That's not how meshing is performed.

Comment: You also need to set zmax to a value less than that used by [restrict z to domain].  The way it works, the plot is clipped at zmax, but you need additional points outside the plot to interpolate the edges.

Comment: That is a really good tip. I am trying, but I am not sure how to add the additional points outside the plot, because the zmax goes in the option of the axis, not of the addplot3, and hence, anything I add outside that limit, will be clipped out.

Comment: Actually, further experiments have shown that the clipping refers to the axis box edges, not the z values.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it but the title is slightly misleading since the question is about plotting a 2d surface in a 3d plot, not a 3d (hyper-)surface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After hours (at least one) of trying to make what is written in the first plot, I thought of polar coordinates. It works.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
    axis equal,
    xmin=-0.1,xmax=5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=3,zmin=-0.4,zmax=7,
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
    axis lines=center]

    \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.5,domain=0.4:2.2,y domain=0:360,samples=40]
    ({x*cos(y)+3}, {x*sin(y)+2}, {1/(x^2)});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, that's a great approach. Thanks for posting, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 9):

`pgfplots` supports the "starred" version `restrict z to domain*` which clips all bigger values into the prescribed domain. The result is a closed cap on top:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=both,restrict z to domain*=0:10]
    \addplot3 [surf,samples=51,
        domain=-2:2,miter limit=1] {1 / (x^2 + y^2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the same with 71 samples:

[image]

Comment: This starred version `restrict z to domain*` seems to fill up all the shapes, or as you described it closes the cap on top. Nevertheless is has to compute the  intersection or cut with the upper boundary beforehand. Which it then also draws. But could one get the same sides without the cap? Basically it comes down to: How to fix only the polygons not being rendered at all ([eg. in the image in the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gx6H.png)), when they should be cut like here?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a possibility using the `sagetex` package and a (free) [SagemathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) account giving you access to a computer algebra system [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) for your LaTeX document. The idea is to generate the data points and for "large" z-values redefine the point to be the maximum z-value on the graph.

```
\documentclass[11pt,border={10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
x = var('x')
y = var('y')
step = .10
x1 = -2
x2 = 2
y1 = -2
y2 = 2
output = ""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]"
output += r"\begin{axis}[xmin=%d, xmax=%d, ymin=%d, ymax=%d]"%(x1,x2,y1,y2-step)
output += r"\addplot3[surf,mesh/rows=%d] coordinates {"%((y2-step-y1)/step+1)
# rows is the number of y values
for y in srange(y1,y2,step):
    for x in srange(x1,x2,step):
        if (1/(x^2+y^2))<10:
            output += r"(%f, %f, %f) "%(x,y,1/(x^2+y^2))
        else:
            output += r"(%f, %f, %f) "%(x,y,10)
output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

Running in SagemathCloud you get this output:
[image]

If you don't mind MetaPost output, the [Function Grapher](http://www.tlhiv.org/mpgraph/) can easily do something similar :

[image]