# 3D Piecewise function using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I would like to know how to draw the discontinuities of a piecewise function, but using the addplot3 (that is, surface). For instance, consider the example here, you can see that the discontinuities are drawn using filled/empty circles. However, in my case, I would like to make an "empty wall" in a 3d graph in order to show such discontinuity. How can I do this?

In the figure below is my plotting, where the wall (you can see the wall from the rectangle at the top to the pyramid starting at z = 0.5) is currently being drawing.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: ["Plotting a 3d surface in tikz, with a limit to the infinity"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333552/plotting-a-3d-surface-in-tikz-with-a-limit-to-the-infinity/333581#333581). The accepted answer includes such a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @DJP. However, my question is different, since I would like to remove all the parts that compose my jump. In the case of my figure, it is all the x and y coordinates with z equal to 0.5 (which compose the "wall")

Comment: What have you done so far? Could you add some code and data points or functions?