# NaN values in 3D scatterplot with colormap

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

Edit:

### I added my code to the question. NaN and zero are both black. I only want zero to be marked black and NaN values have to be transparant.

Is there a way I can make NaN values transparant in a scatter3 plot. In matlab it is possible to ignore NaN values but after using matlab2tikz the NaN values equal zero. 
I tried "unbounded coords=jump" but that did not work for me.

Thanks in advance.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
unbounded coords=jump, 
width=3.739in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.66in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
point meta min=0.5,
point meta max=245,
colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0,0,0); rgb(1pt)=(0.49,0,0); rgb(2pt)= 
(1,0.4,0.3); rgb(3pt)=(1,0.74,0.47); rgb(4pt)=(0,0.57,0); rgb(5pt)= 
(0.4,0.91,0.3)},
xmin=-1100,
xmax=1100,
tick align=outside,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={x},
ymin=-1100,
ymax=1100,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={y},
zmin=0,
zmax=3000,
zlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
zlabel={z},
view={-37.5}{30},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
zmajorgrids,
colorbar
]

\addplot3[scatter,only marks, mark=square*, mark size=1.0607pt, scatter src=explicit, scatter/use mapped color={mark options={}, draw=mapped color, fill=mapped color}] table[row sep=crcr, meta=color, domain=0.5:250]{%
x   y   z   color\\
-440    -560    600 nan\\
-440    -420    600 nan\\
-440    -280    600 nan\\
-440    -140    600 179\\
-440    0   600 nan\\
-440    140 600 241\\
-440    280 600 nan\\
-440    420 600 nan\\
-440    560 600 nan\\
-330    -560    600 nan\\
-330    -420    600 nan\\
-330    -280    600 nan\\
-330    -140    600 nan\\
-330    0   600 nan\\
-330    140 600 nan\\
-330    280 600 nan\\
-330    420 600 nan\\
-330    560 600 nan\\
-220    -560    600 nan\\
-220    -420    600 nan\\
-220    -280    600 nan\\
-220    -140    600 238\\
-220    0   600 nan\\
-220    140 600 0\\
-220    280 600 nan\\
-220    420 600 nan\\
-220    560 600 nan\\
-110    -560    600 235\\
-110    -420    600 nan\\
-110    -280    600 0\\
-110    -140    600 nan\\
-110    0   600 0\\
-110    140 600 nan\\
-110    280 600 235\\
-110    420 600 nan\\
-110    560 600 1\\
0   -560    600 nan\\
0   -420    600 nan\\
0   -280    600 nan\\
0   -140    600 0\\
0   0   600 nan\\
0   140 600 0\\
0   280 600 nan\\
0   420 600 nan\\
0   560 600 nan\\
110 -560    600 0\\
110 -420    600 nan\\
110 -280    600 0\\
110 -140    600 nan\\
110 0   600 0\\
110 140 600 nan\\
110 280 600 0\\
110 420 600 nan\\
110 560 600 195\\
220 -560    600 nan\\
220 -420    600 nan\\
220 -280    600 nan\\
220 -140    600 0\\
220 0   600 nan\\
220 140 600 0\\
220 280 600 nan\\
220 420 600 nan\\
220 560 600 nan\\
330 -560    600 nan\\
330 -420    600 nan\\
330 -280    600 nan\\
330 -140    600 nan\\
330 0   600 nan\\
330 140 600 nan\\
330 280 600 nan\\
330 420 600 nan\\
330 560 600 nan\\
440 -560    600 nan\\
440 -420    600 nan\\
440 -280    600 nan\\
440 -140    600 14\\
440 0   600 nan\\
440 140 600 0\\
440 280 600 nan\\
440 420 600 nan\\
440 560 600 nan\\
-440    -560    700 nan\\
-440    -420    700 nan\\
-440    -280    700 nan\\
-440    -140    700 232\\
-440    0   700 nan\\
-440    140 700 241\\
-440    280 700 nan\\
-440    420 700 nan\\
-440    560 700 nan\\
-330    -560    700 nan\\
-330    -420    700 nan\\
-330    -280    700 nan\\
-330    -140    700 nan\\
-330    0   700 nan\\
-330    140 700 nan\\
-330    280 700 nan\\
-330    420 700 nan\\
-330    560 700 nan\\
-220    -560    700 nan\\
-220    -420    700 nan\\
-220    -280    700 nan\\
-220    -140    700 241\\
-220    0   700 nan\\
-220    140 700 0\\
-220    280 700 nan\\
-220    420 700 nan\\
-220    560 700 nan\\
-110    -560    700 0\\
-110    -420    700 nan\\
-110    -280    700 0\\
-110    -140    700 nan\\
-110    0   700 0\\
-110    140 700 nan\\
-110    280 700 239\\
-110    420 700 nan\\
-110    560 700 233\\
0   -560    700 nan\\
0   -420    700 nan\\
0   -280    700 nan\\
0   -140    700 0\\
0   0   700 nan\\
0   140 700 0\\
0   280 700 nan\\
0   420 700 nan\\
0   560 700 nan\\
110 -560    700 0\\
110 -420    700 nan\\
110 -280    700 0\\
110 -140    700 nan\\
110 0   700 0\\
110 140 700 nan\\
110 280 700 0\\
110 420 700 nan\\
110 560 700 245\\
220 -560    700 nan\\
220 -420    700 nan\\
220 -280    700 nan\\
220 -140    700 0\\
220 0   700 nan\\
220 140 700 0\\
220 280 700 nan\\
220 420 700 nan\\
220 560 700 nan\\
330 -560    700 nan\\
330 -420    700 nan\\
330 -280    700 nan\\
330 -140    700 nan\\
330 0   700 nan\\
330 140 700 nan\\
330 280 700 nan\\
330 420 700 nan\\
330 560 700 nan\\
440 -560    700 nan\\
440 -420    700 nan\\
440 -280    700 nan\\
440 -140    700 0\\
440 0   700 nan\\
440 140 700 0\\
440 280 700 nan\\
440 420 700 nan\\
440 560 700 nan\\
-440    -560    800 nan\\
-440    -420    800 nan\\
-440    -280    800 nan\\
-440    -140    800 226\\
-440    0   800 nan\\
-440    140 800 229\\
-440    280 800 nan\\
-440    420 800 nan\\
-440    560 800 nan\\
-330    -560    800 nan\\
-330    -420    800 nan\\
-330    -280    800 nan\\
-330    -140    800 nan\\
-330    0   800 nan\\
-330    140 800 nan\\
-330    280 800 nan\\
-330    420 800 nan\\
-330    560 800 nan\\
-220    -560    800 nan\\
-220    -420    800 nan\\
-220    -280    800 nan\\
-220    -140    800 229\\
-220    0   800 nan\\
-220    140 800 0\\
-220    280 800 nan\\
-220    420 800 nan\\
-220    560 800 nan\\
-110    -560    800 0\\
-110    -420    800 nan\\
-110    -280    800 0\\
-110    -140    800 nan\\
-110    0   800 207\\
-110    140 800 nan\\
-110    280 800 230\\
-110    420 800 nan\\
-110    560 800 232\\
0   -560    800 nan\\
0   -420    800 nan\\
0   -280    800 nan\\
0   -140    800 231\\
0   0   800 nan\\
0   140 800 0\\
0   280 800 nan\\
0   420 800 nan\\
0   560 800 nan\\
110 -560    800 0\\
110 -420    800 nan\\
110 -280    800 0\\
110 -140    800 nan\\
110 0   800 0\\
110 140 800 nan\\
110 280 800 0\\
110 420 800 nan\\
110 560 800 234\\
220 -560    800 nan\\
220 -420    800 nan\\
220 -280    800 nan\\
220 -140    800 0\\
220 0   800 nan\\
220 140 800 0\\
220 280 800 nan\\
220 420 800 nan\\
220 560 800 nan\\
330 -560    800 nan\\
330 -420    800 nan\\
330 -280    800 nan\\
330 -140    800 nan\\
330 0   800 nan\\
330 140 800 nan\\
330 280 800 nan\\
330 420 800 nan\\
330 560 800 nan\\
440 -560    800 nan\\
440 -420    800 nan\\
440 -280    800 nan\\
440 -140    800 0\\
440 0   800 nan\\
440 140 800 0\\
440 280 800 nan\\
440 420 800 nan\\
440 560 800 nan\\
-440    -560    900 nan\\
-440    -420    900 nan\\
-440    -280    900 nan\\
-440    -140    900 222\\
-440    0   900 nan\\
-440    140 900 216\\
-440    280 900 nan\\
-440    420 900 nan\\
-440    560 900 nan\\
-330    -560    900 nan\\
-330    -420    900 nan\\
-330    -280    900 nan\\
-330    -140    900 nan\\
-330    0   900 nan\\
-330    140 900 nan\\
-330    280 900 nan\\
-330    420 900 nan\\
-330    560 900 nan\\
-220    -560    900 nan\\
-220    -420    900 nan\\
-220    -280    900 nan\\
-220    -140    900 26\\
-220    0   900 nan\\
-220    140 900 0\\
-220    280 900 nan\\
-220    420 900 nan\\
-220    560 900 nan\\
-110    -560    900 102\\
-110    -420    900 nan\\
-110    -280    900 0\\
-110    -140    900 nan\\
-110    0   900 0\\
-110    140 900 nan\\
-110    280 900 214\\
-110    420 900 nan\\
-110    560 900 222\\
0   -560    900 nan\\
0   -420    900 nan\\
0   -280    900 nan\\
0   -140    900 0\\
0   0   900 nan\\
0   140 900 0\\
0   280 900 nan\\
0   420 900 nan\\
0   560 900 nan\\
110 -560    900 209\\
110 -420    900 nan\\
110 -280    900 171\\
110 -140    900 nan\\
110 0   900 0\\
110 140 900 nan\\
110 280 900 1\\
110 420 900 nan\\
110 560 900 15\\
220 -560    900 nan\\
220 -420    900 nan\\
220 -280    900 nan\\
220 -140    900 0\\
220 0   900 nan\\
220 140 900 130\\
220 280 900 nan\\
220 420 900 nan\\
220 560 900 nan\\
330 -560    900 nan\\
330 -420    900 nan\\
330 -280    900 nan\\
330 -140    900 nan\\
330 0   900 nan\\
330 140 900 nan\\
330 280 900 nan\\
330 420 900 nan\\
330 560 900 nan\\
440 -560    900 nan\\
440 -420    900 nan\\
440 -280    900 nan\\
440 -140    900 217\\
440 0   900 nan\\
440 140 900 0\\
440 280 900 nan\\
440 420 900 nan\\
440 560 900 nan\\
-440    -560    1000    nan\\
-440    -420    1000    nan\\
-440    -280    1000    nan\\
-440    -140    1000    225\\
-440    0   1000    nan\\
-440    140 1000    98\\
-440    280 1000    nan\\
-440    420 1000    nan\\
-440    560 1000    nan\\
-330    -560    1000    nan\\
-330    -420    1000    nan\\
-330    -280    1000    nan\\
-330    -140    1000    nan\\
-330    0   1000    nan\\
-330    140 1000    nan\\
-330    280 1000    nan\\
-330    420 1000    nan\\
-330    560 1000    nan\\
-220    -560    1000    nan\\
-220    -420    1000    nan\\
-220    -280    1000    nan\\
-220    -140    1000    202\\
-220    0   1000    nan\\
-220    140 1000    0\\
-220    280 1000    nan\\
-220    420 1000    nan\\
-220    560 1000    nan\\
-110    -560    1000    0\\
-110    -420    1000    nan\\
-110    -280    1000    0\\
-110    -140    1000    nan\\
-110    0   1000    0\\
-110    140 1000    nan\\
-110    280 1000    200\\
-110    420 1000    nan\\
-110    560 1000    206\\
0   -560    1000    nan\\
0   -420    1000    nan\\
0   -280    1000    nan\\
0   -140    1000    0\\
0   0   1000    nan\\
0   140 1000    0\\
0   280 1000    nan\\
0   420 1000    nan\\
0   560 1000    nan\\
110 -560    1000    203\\
110 -420    1000    nan\\
110 -280    1000    200\\
110 -140    1000    nan\\
110 0   1000    158\\
110 140 1000    nan\\
110 280 1000    169\\
110 420 1000    nan\\
110 560 1000    57\\
220 -560    1000    nan\\
220 -420    1000    nan\\
220 -280    1000    nan\\
220 -140    1000    0\\
220 0   1000    nan\\
220 140 1000    17\\
220 280 1000    nan\\
220 420 1000    nan\\
220 560 1000    nan\\
330 -560    1000    nan\\
330 -420    1000    nan\\
330 -280    1000    nan\\
330 -140    1000    nan\\
330 0   1000    nan\\
330 140 1000    nan\\
330 280 1000    nan\\
330 420 1000    nan\\
330 560 1000    nan\\
440 -560    1000    nan\\
440 -420    1000    nan\\
440 -280    1000    nan\\
440 -140    1000    195\\
440 0   1000    nan\\
440 140 1000    0\\
440 280 1000    nan\\
440 420 1000    nan\\
440 560 1000    nan\\
-440    -560    1100    nan\\
-440    -420    1100    nan\\
-440    -280    1100    nan\\
-440    -140    1100    223\\
-440    0   1100    nan\\
-440    140 1100    219\\
-440    280 1100    nan\\
-440    420 1100    nan\\
-440    560 1100    nan\\
-330    -560    1100    nan\\
-330    -420    1100    nan\\
-330    -280    1100    nan\\
-330    -140    1100    nan\\
-330    0   1100    nan\\
-330    140 1100    nan\\
-330    280 1100    nan\\
-330    420 1100    nan\\
-330    560 1100    nan\\
-220    -560    1100    nan\\
-220    -420    1100    nan\\
-220    -280    1100    nan\\
-220    -140    1100    211\\
-220    0   1100    nan\\
-220    140 1100    0\\
-220    280 1100    nan\\
-220    420 1100    nan\\
-220    560 1100    nan\\
-110    -560    1100    124\\
-110    -420    1100    nan\\
-110    -280    1100    0\\
-110    -140    1100    nan\\
-110    0   1100    31\\
-110    140 1100    nan\\
-110    280 1100    183\\
-110    420 1100    nan\\
-110    560 1100    190\\
0   -560    1100    nan\\
0   -420    1100    nan\\
0   -280    1100    nan\\
0   -140    1100    0\\
0   0   1100    nan\\
0   140 1100    0\\
0   280 1100    nan\\
0   420 1100    nan\\
0   560 1100    nan\\
110 -560    1100    190\\
110 -420    1100    nan\\
110 -280    1100    185\\
110 -140    1100    nan\\
110 0   1100    188\\
110 140 1100    nan\\
110 280 1100    76\\
110 420 1100    nan\\
110 560 1100    94\\
220 -560    1100    nan\\
220 -420    1100    nan\\
220 -280    1100    nan\\
220 -140    1100    0\\
220 0   1100    nan\\
220 140 1100    21\\
220 280 1100    nan\\
220 420 1100    nan\\
220 560 1100    nan\\
330 -560    1100    nan\\
330 -420    1100    nan\\
330 -280    1100    nan\\
330 -140    1100    nan\\
330 0   1100    nan\\
330 140 1100    nan\\
330 280 1100    nan\\
330 420 1100    nan\\
330 560 1100    nan\\
440 -560    1100    nan\\
440 -420    1100    nan\\
440 -280    1100    nan\\
440 -140    1100    219\\
440 0   1100    nan\\
440 140 1100    0\\
440 280 1100    nan\\
440 420 1100    nan\\
440 560 1100    nan\\
};
\addplot3[area legend, draw=black, fill=black, forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr] {%
x   y   z\\
135 135 2150\\
135 -135    2150\\
-135    -135    2150\\
-135    135 2150\\
}--cycle;
\addplot3 [color=black]
 table[row sep=crcr] {%
220 1060    800\\
220 -1060   800\\
-220    -1060   800\\
-220    1060    800\\
220 1060    800\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=black]
 table[row sep=crcr] {%
1060    220 800\\
1060    -220    800\\
-1060   -220    800\\
-1060   220 800\\
1060    220 800\\
};

\addplot3[area legend, draw=black, fill=black, forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr] {%
x   y   z\\
135 135 2150\\
135 -135    2150\\
-135    -135    2150\\
-135    135 2150\\
}--cycle;
\addplot3 [color=black]
 table[row sep=crcr] {%
220 1060    800\\
220 -1060   800\\
-220    -1060   800\\
-220    1060    800\\
220 1060    800\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=black]
 table[row sep=crcr] {%
1060    220 800\\
1060    -220    800\\
-1060   -220    800\\
-1060   220 800\\
1060    220 800\\
};

\addplot3[area legend, draw=black, fill=black, forget plot]
table[row sep=crcr] {%
x   y   z\\
135 135 2150\\
135 -135    2150\\
-135    -135    2150\\
-135    135 2150\\
}--cycle;
\addplot3 [color=black]
 table[row sep=crcr] {%
220 1060    800\\
220 -1060   800\\
-220    -1060   800\\
-220    1060    800\\
220 1060    800\\
};
 \addplot3 [color=black]
 table[row sep=crcr] {%
1060    220 800\\
1060    -220    800\\
-1060   -220    800\\
-1060   220 800\\
1060    220 800\\
};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
```

Comment: The question [Plotting a 3d surface in tikz, with a limit to the infinity](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333552/plotting-a-3d-surface-in-tikz-with-a-limit-to-the-infinity/333581#333581) mentions, in Christian Feuersänger's answer, `restrict z to domain*`.

Comment: That is not exactly what i mean. A part of my script looks like this:
\addplot3[scatter, only marks, mark=square*, mark size=1.0607pt, scatter src=explicit, scatter/use mapped color={mark options={}, draw=mapped color, fill=mapped color}] table[row sep=crcr, meta=color]{%
x y z color\\
-440 -560 600 nan\\
-440 -420 600 nan\\
-440 -280 600 nan\\
-440 -140 600 179\\
-440 0 600 nan\\
-440 140 600 241\\
And from this data i want to ignore the nan values.

Comment: Please do not post parts of codes in comments. Rather, provide a complete minimal working example in the question.