# How to graph a 3D surface with "holes"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, miktex, 3d, overleaf

I would like to plot the surface [image] over [image]. I cannot figure out how to show the two "holes" of the surface that result due to its intersection with the [image] plane.

I tried the following but I cannot get the holes to be smooth given the limited samples that I am only afforded.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
width=15cm,
view={120}{45},
enlargelimits=false,
grid=major,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel=$\varphi$, xmin=-5,xmax=5, ymin=-5,ymax=5, zmin=-1,zmax=10
]
\addplot3[] (0,0,0);
\def\ra{0.58}\def\ga{0.26}\def\ba{0.64}
\def\rb{0.91}\def\gb{0.85}\def\bb{0.92}
\addplot3[patch, patch type=bilinear,
mesh/color input=explicit mathparse, samples=66,
z buffer=sort,
domain=-1:1,
y domain=-2:2, restrict z to domain=0:10,
opacity=0.8,
point meta={symbolic={\rb+(10-z)/10*(\ra-\rb),
\gb+(10-z)/10*(\ga-\gb),
\bb+(10-z)/10*(\ba-\bb)}},]
({x}, {y}, {2/sqrt((x*x) + ((y-1)*(y-1))) + 1/sqrt((x*x) + ((y+1)*(y+1)))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also tried parametrizing around the holes but I do not know how to complete the rest of the graph. Please advise. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
width=15cm,
view={120}{45},
enlargelimits=false,
grid=major,
samples=20, 
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel=$\varphi$, xmin=-5,xmax=5, ymin=-5,ymax=5, zmin=0,zmax=10
]

\addplot3[] (0,0,0);

\def\ra{0.58}\def\ga{0.26}\def\ba{0.64}
\def\rb{0.91}\def\gb{0.85}\def\bb{0.92}

\addplot3[patch,patch type=bilinear,
mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
z buffer=sort, samples = 40,
domain=0.1:1,
y domain=0:2*pi,
opacity=0.6,
point meta={symbolic={\rb+((10-z)/10)*(\ra-\rb),
\gb+((10-z)/10)*(\ga-\gb),
\bb+((10-z)/10)*(\ba-\bb)}}]
({x*cos(deg(y))}, {-1+x*sin(deg(y))}, {min(2/sqrt(x*x - (4*x*sin(deg(y))) + 4) + 1/sqrt(x*x), 10)});

\addplot3[patch,patch type=bilinear,
mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
z buffer=sort,samples=40,
domain=0.2:1,
y domain=0:2*pi,
opacity=0.6,
point meta={symbolic={\rb+((10-z)/10)*(\ra-\rb),
\gb+((10-z)/10)*(\ga-\gb),
\bb+((10-z)/10)*(\ba-\bb)}}]
({x*cos(deg(y))}, {1+x*sin(deg(y))}, {min(2/sqrt(x*x) + 1/sqrt(x*x + (4*x*sin(deg(y))) + 4), 10)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Truncating singular 3d surface plot with large values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562145/truncating-singular-3d-surface-plot-with-large-values/562666#562666). There are 5 different answers provided.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to that question but the solutions given do not seem to be satisfactory ones though. Among the five approaches, only the fourth one really answer the problem but I cannot compile that either on Overleaf online or locally using MikTex/TeXworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for `fun`.

Compile with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

Run in `cmd`: `asy -f pdf -render=4 xcvxc.asy` (for pdf)

Run in `cmd`: `asy -noprc -f pdf -V -render=4 xcvxc.asy` (for interaction)

```
// name: xcvxc.asy

import graph3;
import smoothcontour3;
import contour3;
import palette;

size(12cm,IgnoreAspect);
currentprojection=orthographic(1,-2,1);

real f(real x, real y, real z) {return 2/(sqrt(x^2+(y-1)^2))+1/(sqrt(x^2+(y+1)^2))-z;}

// Code 1 (recommended)
surface s=implicitsurface(f,(-1,-2,0),(2,2,6),overlapedges=true);
s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()));
draw(s,render(merge=true));

/*
// Code 2
surface s=surface(contour3(f,(-1,-2,0),(2,2,5),25)); 
// > 30, for my computer, error: out of memory
s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()));
draw(s,render(compression=Low,merge=true));
*/

xaxis3("$x$",Bounds,InTicks);
yaxis3("$y$",Bounds,InTicks(beginlabel=false));
zaxis3("$z$",Bounds,InTicks);
```

Code 1:

[image]

Code 2:

[image]

For more information, see [smoothcontour3](https://github.com/charlesstaats/smoothcontour3).
or have look at [here](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/3Dgraphs/magnetic.html).

Comment: Can you please check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564787/can-i-remove-the-front-planes-of-the-3d-grid-when-using-the-asymptote-package/564827#564827)? I am wondering why yours rendered without the surface overlapping the front planes. Thanks.